# Image retrieval - edge histogram

Tags: image-processing, graphics, computer-vision

My lecturer has slides on `edge histograms` for `image retrieval`, whereby he states that one must first divide the image into `4x4 blocks`, and then check for edges at the `horizontal, vertical, +45°, and -45° orientations`. He then states that this is then represented in a `14x1 histogram`. I have no idea how he came about deciding that a `14x1 histogram` must be created. Does anyone know how he came up with this value, or how to create an `edge histogram`?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing you are referring to is called the Histogram of Oriented Gradients (HoG). However, the math doesn't work out for your example. Normally you will choose spatial binning parameters (the 4x4 blocks). For each block, you'll compute the gradient magnitude at some number of different directions (in your case, just 2 directions). So, in each block you'll have `N_{directions}` measurements. Multiply this by the number of blocks (16 for you), and you see that you have `16*N_{directions}` total measurements.

To form the histogram, you simply concatenate these measurements into one long vector. Any way to do the concatenation is fine as long as you keep track of the way you map the bin/direction combo into a slot in the 1-D histogram. This long histogram of concatenations is then most often used for machine learning tasks, like training a classifier to recognize some aspect of images based upon the way their gradients are oriented.

But in your case, the professor must be doing something special, because if you have 16 different image blocks (a 4x4 grid of image blocks), then you'd need to compute less than 1 measurement per block to end up with a total of 14 measurements in the overall histogram.

Alternatively, the professor might mean that you take the range of angles in between [-45,+45] and you divide that into 14 different values: -45, -45 + 90/14, -45 + 2*90/14, ... and so on.

If that is what the professor means, then in that case you get 14 orientation bins within a single block. Once everything is concatenated, you'd have one very long 14*16 = 224-component vector describing the whole image overall.

Incidentally, I have done a lot of testing with Python implementations of Histogram of Gradient, so you can see some of the work linked [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~ely/faceparts/index.html) or [here](http://people.seas.harvard.edu/~ely/faceparts/about.html). There is also some example code at that site, though a more well-supported version of HoG appears in [scikits.image](http://scikits-image.org/).

Comment: Why is there just 2 directions in mine? Surely there is 4. Left to right, up to down, bottom left to top right, and top left to bottom right. Would you mind explaining the histogram slightly more? I'm quite confused how the gradient magnitudes are used to create a histogram. I have always seen histograms to have frequency on the Y-axis, but I am not sure what the frequency is in this case.

Comment: When I said there were just 2 directions, I was going by your first post, where you only said +/- 45 degrees. Obviously, in practice, you'd want to have more directions than this, which I clarified later when I said that your professor might mean for you to take all the directions between -45 and +45 and discretize them into a grid of directions. There are two different approaches. Sometimes people will discretize the entire circle of directions, other times they will only discretize half of the circle. Most usually, you only care about the absolute direction and the sign doesn't matter.

Comment: As for the "frequency" axis, in this case you will compute a whole new "image" where each "pixel" contains the magnitude of the gradient at that pixel. If the pixel at (i,j) has gradient magnitude M and gradient direction D, then you figure out which angular bin the direction D belongs to (based on your chosen discretized angle grid), and in that slot of the histogram you add the magnitude M. So the "frequency" that a given pixel contributes to the histogram is the gradient's magnitude at that pixel.

Comment: In practice, most people take the angles between 0 and pi and they discretize it into 11 or 15 bins. Then for each block of image, they loop through this list of angles and they add up the total gradient magnitude from pixels in that block that contribute to that particular angle bin, and then insert this sum into the histogram for that block. They repeat this for the next block, and so on, obtaining several such histograms. Then when all is said and done, they simply concatenate the histograms together to make one looong histogram that serves as the descriptor.

Comment: If you write code to do this, usually it will accept any patch of an image as the input, and then it will chop that patch up into blocks, chop angles up into bins, and compute the above mentioned long histogram as the output. In this manner, you can get a descriptor of any given image patch. If you wanted to ask whether two image patches were similar to each other, for example, you could compute the distance between their descriptors. Or you could manually classify images of a certain object with a +1 and train a classifier to recognize those images based upon their descriptors.

Comment: So, to confirm my understanding of your comments, my histogram would have four bins representing the different angles I have specified, and the Y-axis becomes the total magnitude of those angles for each 4x4 block. If, for example, I have a 16x16 image, then I will have 64 bins.

Comment: Who knows how my lecturer came up with a 14 bin histogram, however I know it isn't a mistake. The only way I can possibly think of achieving such a result (except, as you mentioned, descretising it into 14 possible angles), is if you only use +45 and -45 degree 4x4 blocks and calculate the gradient magnitude along the diagonal direction with a 1 pixel width, where there is 7 for each block.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Each block will yield a 4-vector with a component for the different directions `[d1, d2, d3, d4]`, where d1 is left-right, d2 is top-right-to-bottom-left, and so on. In the d1-component, you'll store the sum of gradient magnitudes pointing in that direction, in that block. Repeat for each direction and you've got a block-level histogram. Repeat all that for each block and you've got 16 different block-level histograms. Stack them all together and you'll have one single image-level histogram that is 16*4 = 64 components long.